# Can you help me expand this trill in Mozart's Sonata 16 (k545)?

Tags: sheet-music, classical-music, ornaments, classical-period

I wonder if I am reading it wrong, or if i need much more practice on this segment. It simply doesn't sound right when I play it. Can you help me expand this trill into actual notes on the sheet please?
[image]

Comment: FYI, your title has a typo. Did you mean "Can you help me..." or "How do you..."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are how to play it and variations.

[image: Trill as played]

[image: Variation]

**Note-** the speed of the trill can be altered to suit the piece.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.oldflutes.com/articles/classicaltrill/index.htm) documents that Mozart's trills started on the upper note, either directly or suspended. Also, the jump from G to E in Luke's answer is certainly wrong. I would suggest continuing to hold the G for one 16th, then FEF as equal 16ths.

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to the previews for free on iTunes or any online music store.

[Mitsuko Uchida](https://music.apple.com/us/album/piano-sonata-no-16-in-c-k-545-sonata-facile-1-allegro/1452230122?i=1452230805) and most performers play it as FGFGFEF:
[image: FGFGFEF]

though it is also [acceptable](https://music.apple.com/album/piano-sonata-no-16-in-c-major/356737757) to play it as a turn (FGFEF):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

trill is a rapid oscillation between the written note and the note above. In the Mozart case, the F is expanded into FG, or FGFG if you like.